# Navigate to a website and set claims

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory, claims-based-identity

I need to navigate to a web site and set a number of claims for that web site to use, but I cannot find any explanation on how to do it. I must be googling the wrong words.

I'm using c# and .Net framework 4.6.1

## Edit 1

I was asked to explain my challenge better. I am developing 2 separate websites. Users will always go to website A where they will authenticated using Azure B2C. Once authenticated they will perform a few actions after which they will be navigated to website B. Azure B2C passes user data to website A using Claims, which I would like to forward to website B

Comment: Please don't down vote something without explaining why! What is wrong with my question?

Comment: *I'm not the downvoter* - Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I think i asked a question similar to yours. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34690705/asp-net-dynamic-user-and-activity-based-authorisation-mixed-with-hide-show-site

Answer (score 0):

A claim from website A will not be sent to website B.

This could work this way:

1. A users logs on to site A (using credentials from B2C)
2. User saves info into B2C (using Graph API)
3. Redirect to Site B
4. User logs on to site B (this can occur without prompting the user, same B2C)
5. Claim are created for site B, but they can contain values set during step 2

graph API:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet/

---

If the info is already in the B2C directory, the example is even more simple, create 2 sites:
https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-dotnet/

Create a custom attribute to store the information:
https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-reference-custom-attr/

- Create a B2C custom attribute:
- Create 2(both) B2C Applications
- Create a single B2C sign-in policy using the custom attribute and add it to the claims
- Use the same policy in both applications, both should see the same claim

Comment: Thanks Erik, can you please explain your first statement? Why will it not be sent? I specifically do not want to save the data that is already in B2C in my own database, for duplication and information security reasons. If the B2C website can pass my website claims, why can I not forward some of them?

Comment: A claim is created by a Security Token Service (STS) in this case B2C. and is specially crafted for each website and may contain sensitive information for one website. You can instruct the second website to single sign on the already signed in user and create a new claim for site B, so no seperate database is needed. So you're solution is right, but it is accomplished with a second claim instead of forwarding the original

Comment: Thanks Erik, I'll be happy to craft new claim(s). I am however having a very hard time finding out how to do this, create claim(s) and pass them to a website as you navigate to it. Can you point me at some sample code that shows how to do this?

Comment: No code is needed, see the edited answer, B2C handles the claims part for you

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to expose a new login action in your website B. This login action can receive an encrypted token which inside contains the claims you are interested in forwarding to the site B. Once that encrypted token is received, the website B can decrypt it and recreate the claims that you are interested in. You can use the built in JwtSecurityToken Handler:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwtsecuritytokenhandler(v=vs.114).aspx

For example:

```
public string CreateSecurityToken(string audience, IEnumerable<Claim> claims)
    {
        if (claims == null) return null;
        var credentials = new SigningCredentials(
                new InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("SOMEKEY")),
                "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#hmac-sha256",
                "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256");

        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Custom Authentication", System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name, System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Role);
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = claimsIdentity,
            TokenIssuerName = TokenIssuer,
            AppliesToAddress = "http://" + audience,
            Lifetime = new Lifetime(DateTime.UtcNow, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(GetTokenExpirationMinutes(audience))),
            SigningCredentials = credentials
        };
        var jwtHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var token = jwtHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        return jwtHandler.WriteToken(token);
    }
```

this will create a token which you can send to a login method on website B

Comment: Thanks Luis, would I then call the Login method and do a Server.Transfer? Would that preserve the login session? I apologise if these are noob questions, they are coming from a noob :)

Comment: You would need to create a new  session on your other application with your claims encoded in your encrypted token